# How to use React component that uses Kendo grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, kendo-grid

I have to use react component(built by other team) which uses Kendo grid but in my project, we are not using Kendo.

I see, that after using that component ; all styles are missing from the same.Should i explicitly use kendo css for this, is it feasible? 
Thanks

**This is working now**, have installed kendo theme and added its css.

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-default
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';
```

Comment: Maybe you can replace the Kendo grid classes with your own? That might be a limited set of classes to change?

Comment: ok,thanks. i think that would need a little effort to check what and all css is being used.Since the component is from other team , code is all minified. Again it would be a copy paste from kendo css only, i suppose.i tried to use kendo.min.css but it was pointing to png file so got error.

Comment: Probably best to use kendo.min.css but you might look at the non minified version and pull out just the classes you need; it's a pretty well documented framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed kendo theme and added its css.

npm install --save @progress/kendo-theme-default
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';